# Naming the groups for which the rows are aggregated

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, rename

I have data as follows:

```
DT <- structure(list(Area = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B"), Year = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2), Group = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), Population_Count = c(10, 
12, 12, 10, 12, 12, 10, 13, 13, 10, 11, 12), Male_Count = c(5, 
7, 7, 5, 4, 7, 5, 8, 8, 5, 6, 7), Female_Count = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 
8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 12 x 6
   Area   Year Group Population_Count Male_Count Female_Count
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 A         1     1               10          5            5
 2 A         1     2               12          7            5
 3 A         1     3               12          7            5
 4 A         2     1               10          5            5
 5 A         2     2               12          4            8
 6 A         2     3               12          7            5
 7 B         1     1               10          5            5
 8 B         1     2               13          8            5
 9 B         1     3               13          8            5
10 B         2     1               10          5            5
11 B         2     2               11          6            5
12 B         2     3               12          7            5
```

I would like to tell this data that I want to aggregate `Group==1` and `Group==2`, for all columns.

I tried:

```
DT <- data.table::setDT(DT)[Group==1 | Group==2 ,lapply(Filter(is.numeric,.SD),sum, na.rm=TRUE), by=c("Area", "Year")]

   Area Year Group Population_Count Male_Count Female_Count
1:    A    1     3               22         12           10
2:    A    2     3               22          9           13
3:    B    1     3               23         13           10
4:    B    2     3               21         11           10
```

Which works well, but this subsets the data, and I would like to be able to name the new group, when running the code (and not after, because `Group==3` already exists). Is there a way to do that? Or do I have to rename the groups beforehand?

Desired result:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 6
  Area   Year Group     Population_Count Male_Count Female_Count
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>                <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
1 A         1 New_group               22         12           10
2 A         2 New_group               22          9           13
3 B         1 New_group               23         13           10
4 B         2 New_group               21         11           10
5 A         1 3                       12          7            5
6 A         2 3                       12          7            5
7 B         1 3                       13          8            5
8 B         2 3                       12          7            5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think renaming groups beforehand would be a good option. Rename groups with value 1 and 2 to some common value (99 here) and then do group by sum.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(DT)[Group %in% c(1, 2), Group := 99]
DT[, lapply(.SD, sum), .(Area, Year, Group)]

#   Area Year Group Population_Count Male_Count Female_Count
#1:    A    1    99               22         12           10
#2:    A    1     3               12          7            5
#3:    A    2    99               22          9           13
#4:    A    2     3               12          7            5
#5:    B    1    99               23         13           10
#6:    B    1     3               13          8            5
#7:    B    2    99               21         11           10
#8:    B    2     3               12          7            5
```